# get bag info from http request

Tags: javascript, python, https, xmlhttprequest, python-requests

I am trying to get product info using http requests from a user's "bag" or "cart" on a product's checkout webpage.  I added an item to the the shopping bag and then sent a request to the website's "bag" webpage; however, the request is sending back data as if nothing has been added to the bag.  The results of the http request depict a blank checkout page.  I assume the problem is that the webpage that I am trying to get data from does not recognize the http request is coming from the same origin that added an item to shopping bag.  Is there a way that I can edit the header of my http request so that the website will return the appropriate data?  Is there any other modification that I can make to my http request that will return the desired results?  Here is a basic example of code that I am running in python, which is not returning the desired results.  Eventually I want to use xmlhttprequests in javascript to perform this operation.

```
checkoutURL = "www.arbitrarycustomercheckout.com"

bagInfo = requests.get(checkoutURL).content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(bagInfo)

for link in soup.findAll('htmlele'):
    print link.get("htmlAttr"), link
print
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to look at cookies.

If you send the cookie from the session where you added something to the cart with your new request it should work properly.

Comment: Thank you.  How do I access the cookie when something is sent to my cart?

Comment: That depends. Where do you add something to your cart? Your Browser, requests,..?

Comment: Ideally yes, However I am not sure if I can perform an action like clicking a button through an http request.  If not the item would be added to the bag immediately before the http request is launched.  Thank you for your help.